# Drawing a Bezier curve Android drawing app is very slow

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, bezier

I have been working on an Android drawing application, which is meant to draw a Bezier line, based upon user interaction. The user draws the line on the screen and it appears exactly as they have drawn it.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    touchX = event.getX();
    touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawingElement = new DrawingElement(gridType, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            drawingElement.addPoint(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawingElement.addPoint(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawingElement.addPoint(touchX, touchY);

                actualDrawingElement = new DrawPath(gridType, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, drawPaint, paintColor, brushSize);
                actualDrawingElement.setDrawingElementType(DrawingElementType.PATH);

            actualDrawingElement.setPoints(drawingElement.getPoints());
            drawingElement = actualDrawingElement;
            actualDrawingElement = null;
            finishedElement = true;

            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }




//draw the view - will be called after touch event
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if(bgPaint == null) {
        bgPaint = new Paint();
        bgPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), bgPaint);

    Bitmap dbBMP =  null;
    BitmapSave bitmapSave = getDatabaseHandler().getLastSave();
    if(bitmapSave != null) {
        dbBMP = bitmapSave.getBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    } else {
        dbBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getActualWidth(), (int) getActualHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    Canvas dbCanvas = new Canvas(dbBMP);

    DrawPath p;
    if(drawingElement != null && drawingElement.getPointCount() > 0) {
        actualDrawingElement = new DrawPath(gridType, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, drawPaint, paintColor, brushSize);
        actualDrawingElement.setDrawingElementType(DrawingElementType.PATH);
        actualDrawingElement.setPoints(drawingElement.getPoints());
        p = (DrawPath)actualDrawingElement;
        p.draw(dbCanvas);
        p = null;

    }

    if(finishedElement) {
        db.addSave(new BitmapSave(dbBMP));
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(dbBMP, 0, 0, drawPaint);

    if(displayGrid) {
        DrawGrid drawGrid = new DrawGrid(gridType, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, bgPaint);
        drawGrid.draw(canvas);
    }

    updateUndoRedoButtons();
}
```

The above code shows my onDraw and onTouchEvent methods. I moved to using a database to store the bitmaps as I started to get a lot of memory overload errors and it would crash. Previously I had multiple bitmaps in memory for undo/redo inside an ArrayList (would get to max. 3 or 4 before crashing). I would like to have at least 20 undos/redos (in total) in the app.

In the end it is meant to draw multiple lines at the same time, but even one line is slow.

I have tried to abstract a few things happening, eg. the line drawing...
It does store the points in a separate class, which it grabs them later on to draw.

Abstracted line drawing method is...

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    boolean firstRun = true;

    Point2D prevPoints = null;
    Point2D points = null;
    for(Point2D pointGrp : getPoints()) {
        points = getCalculatedPoints(pointGrp);
            if (firstRun) {
                paths.add(new Path());
                paths.get(0).moveTo(points.getPosX(), points.getPosY());
            } else {
                paths.get(0).quadTo(prevPoints.getPosX(), prevPoints.getPosY(), points.getPosX(), points.getPosY());
            }
        firstRun = false;
        prevPoints = points;
    }

    canvas.drawPath(paths.get(0), getPaint());
}
```

At this stage "points = getCalculatedPoints(pointGrp);" literally returns the same point it is give. Point2D object just holds pointx, and pointy nothing else. Has no methods other then getters and setters.

Any ideas why this would be running really slow? It only picks up 4 points across a massive line, making it very jagged and straight.

Comment: "I would like to have at least 20 undos/redos (in total) in the app" -- don't use bitmaps for undo/redo. Keep track of the key data about your lines and redraw them. Beyond that, use Traceview to determine where you are spending your time, other than in the bitmap copying. Also, it looks like perhaps you are doing database I/O in `onDraw()`, which, if true, is really really bad and would explain your problems.

Comment: You are reconstructing the bitmap from the database on each onDraw call, instead of that keep in memory the last bitmap and just draw the new data to it, and restore from the database only if you have to roll back.

Comment: I have kept the key data for my lines previously and not used Bitmaps. It caused the app to work ok for about 3 lines (if they were short!) then it got horribly slow and did not pick up enough points in the lines. I will attempt to restrict db access to when needed but have previously not used the database and just bitmaps. It was slow basically from word go with that setup too.

Is there a better method for storing data? Or it is not right that I have been experiencing low memory issues?

Comment: why not just exclusively store the input event coordinates that you use for drawing your curves, and then simply use those to redraw the curves as your user's drawing them? There doesn't seem to be any need for bitmaps here.